# Is there a way to get the variables that were used in a RegEx.Replace to use in .NET?

Tags: .net, regex

For example, i have a pattern that i am searching for using the \G option so it remembers its last search.  I would like to be able to reuse these in .NET c# (ie: save the matches into a collection)

For Example:

```
string pattern = @"\G<test:Some\s.*";
string id = RegEx.Match(orig, pattern).Value;  
// The guy above has 3 matches and i want to save all three into a generic list
```

I hope this is clear, i can elaborate if not.

thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the RegEx.Matches function and iterate through the collection.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am trying this but with no luck - when i use RegEx.Match(orig, pattern) it works, if i do:

MatchCollection co = RegEx.Matches(orig, pattern); 

I get 0 results.  Any idea what im doing wrong here?